# PHP mail contact form not submitting on nginx: 405 (not allowed) with request method POST

Tags: javascript, php, nginx, contact-form, mail-server

[Contact Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3fuKx.png) -- [Chrome Debug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L4rax.png)

I'm building a contact form for my personal website: cormaccrowley.com, but the contact form is not submitting.  I don't understand what the problem is but I'll post all the info I think is relevant.  The site is running on nginx with an https:// security protocol.  Problems I've considered - Cross-Origin-Resource-Sharing (CORS) issue.  I've changed all 'POST' to 'GET' and that didn't help.  I've worked on the server side trying to install both sendmail and postfix as well as setting up zoho email servers for my domain.  Unfortunately, I don't think the contact form is even submitting - something is wrong with the javascript or php file.

## TL;DR

My contact form is not running! The file contact_me.php seems to be causing the error.  Chrome inspect tools says (see chrome debuc link):

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405 (Not Allowed)

POST https://cormaccrowley.com/contact_me.php 405 (Not Allowed)

### This is the file that seems to be causing the problem: contact_me.php

```
<?php
// Check for empty fields
if(empty($_POST['name'])        ||
   empty($_POST['email'])       ||
   empty($_POST['phone'])       ||
   empty($_POST['message']) ||
   !filter_var($_POST['email'],FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
   {
    echo "No arguments Provided!";
    return false;
   }

$name = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']));
$email_address = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']));
$phone = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['phone']));
$message = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['message']));

// Create the email and send the message
$to = 'c[MY-EMAIL-WAS-HERE]'; // Add your email address inbetween the '' replacing yourname@yourdomain.com - This is where the form will send a message to.
$email_subject = "Website Contact Form:  $name";
$email_body = "You have received a new message from your website contact form.\n\n"."Here are the details:\n\nName: $name\n\nEmail: $email_address\n\nPhone: $phone\n\nMessage:\n$message";
$headers = "From: noreply@cormaccrowley.com\n"; // This is the email address the generated message will be from. We recommend using something like noreply@yourdomain.com.
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email_address"; 
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
return true;            
?>
```

## Here is the Code for the contact form:

```
<!-- Contact Section -->
<section id="contact">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
                <h2>Contact Me</h2>
                <hr class="star-primary">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
                <!-- To configure the contact form email address, go to mail/contact_me.php and update the email address in the PHP file on line 19. -->
                <!-- The form should work on most web servers, but if the form is not working you may need to configure your web server differently. -->
                <form name="sentMessage" id="contactForm" novalidate>
                    <div class="row control-group">
                        <div class="form-group col-xs-12 floating-label-form-group controls">
                            <label for="name">Name</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" id="name" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your name.">
                            <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row control-group">
                        <div class="form-group col-xs-12 floating-label-form-group controls">
                            <label for="email">Email Address</label>
                            <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email Address" id="email" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your email address.">
                            <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row control-group">
                        <div class="form-group col-xs-12 floating-label-form-group controls">
                            <label for="phone">Phone Number</label>
                            <input type="tel" class="form-control" placeholder="Phone Number" id="phone" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your phone number.">
                            <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row control-group">
                        <div class="form-group col-xs-12 floating-label-form-group controls">
                            <label for="message">Message</label>
                            <textarea rows="5" class="form-control" placeholder="Message" id="message" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter a message."></textarea>
                            <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <div id="success"></div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="form-group col-xs-12">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg">Send</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

## This is the Javascript form handler:

```
$(function() {

$("#contactForm input,#contactForm textarea").jqBootstrapValidation({
    preventSubmit: true,
    submitError: function($form, event, errors) {
        // additional error messages or events
    },
    submitSuccess: function($form, event) {
        // Prevent spam click and default submit behaviour
        $("#btnSubmit").attr("disabled", true);
        event.preventDefault();

        // get values from FORM
        var name = $("input#name").val();
        var email = $("input#email").val();
        var phone = $("input#phone").val();
        var message = $("textarea#message").val();
        var firstName = name; // For Success/Failure Message
        // Check for white space in name for Success/Fail message
        if (firstName.indexOf(' ') >= 0) {
            firstName = name.split(' ').slice(0, -1).join(' ');
        }
        $.ajax({
            url: "../contact_me.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                name: name,
                phone: phone,
                email: email,
                message: message
            },
            cache: false,
            success: function() {
                // Enable button & show success message
                $("#btnSubmit").attr("disabled", false);
                $('#success').html("<div class='alert alert-success'>");
                $('#success > .alert-success').html("<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;")
                    .append("</button>");
                $('#success > .alert-success')
                    .append("<strong>Your message has been sent. </strong>");
                $('#success > .alert-success')
                    .append('</div>');

                //clear all fields
                $('#contactForm').trigger("reset");
            },
            error: function() {
                // Fail message
                $('#success').html("<div class='alert alert-danger'>");
                $('#success > .alert-danger').html("<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;")
                    .append("</button>");
                $('#success > .alert-danger').append("<strong>Sorry " + firstName + ", it seems that my mail server is not responding. Please try again later!");
                $('#success > .alert-danger').append('</div>');
                //clear all fields
                $('#contactForm').trigger("reset");
            },
        });
    },
    filter: function() {
        return $(this).is(":visible");
    },
});

$("a[data-toggle=\"tab\"]").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).tab("show");
});
});

// When clicking on Full hide fail/success boxes
$('#name').focus(function() {
$('#success').html('');
});
```

## This is my nginx.conf file

```
    user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
        worker_connections 768;
        # multi_accept on;
}

http {

        ##
        # Basic Settings
        ##

        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        tcp_nodelay on;
        keepalive_timeout 65;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;
        # server_tokens off;

        # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
        # server_name_in_redirect off;

        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

        ##
        # SSL Settings
        ##

        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        ##
        # Logging Settings
        ##

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        ##
        # Gzip Settings
        ##
    gzip on;
        gzip_disable "msie6";

        # gzip_vary on;
        # gzip_proxied any;
        # gzip_comp_level 6;
        # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
        # gzip_http_version 1.1;
        # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/$

        ##
        # Virtual Host Configs
        ##

        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

## And this is my sites-enabled default server-block on nginx

```
server {
        listen 80;
        root /var/www/cormaccrowley;

        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        #added contact_me.php in attempt to fix contact form

        server_name cormaccrowley.com;
        #ssl_certificate      /etc/nginx/ssl/cormaccrowley.com.chained.crt;
        #ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/cormaccrowley.key;

        return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;

        #location / {
        #       # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        #       # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        #       try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        #
        #       ##
        #}


}

server {
        #ssl stuff - careful - jeeeeez
        root /var/www/cormaccrowley;
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name cormaccrowley.com;
        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/cormaccrowley.com.chained.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/cormaccrowley.key;

        #Adding CORS stuff from internet
        #End CORS stuff
}
```

**Thank you so much in advance.  I've tried for the last 2 days to fix this contact form and I don't seem to be making any progress.  Suggestions, tips, answers, and references are all appreciated**

Comment: I was going to mark it as tl;tr, but you added a detailed [mcve]. Good job. For the PHP code, you are returning a value for `include` or `require`. Are you expecting that? Otherwise for debugging purposes, use `die()`. Also, depending on each server environment, mail headers should include `PHP_EOL` instead of just `\n` which would work on Linux, but not all Windows versions. However, this would not fix the issue you're having, its more or less a guideline.

Comment: I'm running a unix distribution on digital ocean (nginx).  And thank you - I've tried to supply all resources :).  What is die() and how can I use it? Are you referring to the includes in the nginx config files?

Comment: I am referring to `return false` outside of a function. Yes, it will quit the script from executing any further, but it would tell me at the same time you are expecting that as you might do `$var = include 'sendmail.php'`. Now `$var` will either hold true or false depending on how the script executed. If this isn't the case, you should use `die()` as it will halt the entire request.

Comment: I am a bit confused by your wording.  Can you post the full php code with your edits so I can see how to implement die instead of return false?